# How to exclude the words that have non-alphabetic characters from string

Tags: java, arrays, string, non-alphanumeric

For example, if I want to delete the non-alphabetic characters I would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i] = s[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
}
```

How do I completely exclude a word with a non-alphabetic character from the string?

For example:
Initial input:

```
"a cat jumped jumped; on the table"
```

It should exclude "jumped;" because of ";".

Output:

```
"a cat jumped on the table"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `exclude a word ... from my array`? Arrays can't change its length. Do you want to replace such word with empty String?

Comment: Do you have an array of words, and you want to remove the words with non-alphabetic characters? Please give example input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Do you want to create a new, shorter array, lacking the word you want to exclude? This would all be a little easier with a list instead of an array.

Comment: @Pshemo If this is the case, then I guess i should exclude the words before storing them in a string array.

Comment: @user3383621 I will ask little different. Lets say you want to exclude word `"foo"` from `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`. What result should look like? If result should be `["bar", "baz"]` then you should use Collection like `List` instead of array.

Comment: @Pshemo I think i shouldn't have said "exclude from an array". What i need is: I have an input string. It should be stored in the array of valid words. I guess that I need to take out the illegal words first and then create an array.

Comment: I edited my question so it's more understandable. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: That edit made the problem easier, but kinda invalidated all your current answers...

Comment: There are a lot of these type questions today.. are you in some sort of class? Earlier it was in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** (in response to your edit)

You could do this:

```
String input = "a cat jumped jumped; on the table";
input = input.replaceAll("(^| )[^ ]*[^A-Za-z ][^ ]*(?=$| )", "");
```

Let's break down the regex:

- `(^| )` matches after the beginning of a word, either after a space or after the start of the string.
- `[^ ]*` matches any sequence, including the null string, of non-spaces (because spaces break the word)
- `[^A-Za-z ]` checks if the character is non-alphabetical and does not break the string.
- Lastly, we need to append `[^ ]*` to make it match until the end of the word.
- `(?=$| )` matches the end of the word, either the end of the string or the next space character, but it doesn't consume the next space, so that consecutive words will still match (ie `"I want to say hello, world! everybody"` becomes `"I want to say everybody"`)

Note: if `"a cat jumped off the table."` should output `"a cat jumped off the table"`, then use this:

```
input = input.replaceAll(" [^ ]*[^A-Za-z ][^ ]*(?= )", "").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]$", "");
```

---

Assuming you have 1 word per array element, you can do this to replace them with the empty string:

```
for (String string: s) {
    if (s.matches(".*[^A-Za-z].*") {
        s = "";
    }
}
```

If you actually want to remove it, consider using an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int index = 0; index < s.length; index++) {
    if (s[index].matches(".*[^A-Za-z].*") {
        stringList.add(s[index]);
    }
}
```

And the `ArrayList` will have all the elements that don't have non-alphabetical characters in them.

Comment: it won't match "123abass;[;[]" :)

Comment: @Quincunx thank you for explaining it both for array and string!

Comment: @Quincunx  i tested out all the methods to make sure i understand, but for some reason the "." wouldn't get removed. Why?

Comment: @Quincunx In all of them, I had to add another `.replaceAll("\\.", "")` (which is probably a dumb solution) to the first code option, and then it took out the dots.

Comment: @user3383621 All of what cases? You did not give me anything. The only case you gave is `"a cat jumped jumped; on the table"`. I'm not psychic.

Comment: @Quincunx I misunderstood you. I thought you were referring to in what type of code implementation it didn't work. It didn't work in a case like `"a cat jumped on the table."` (it didn't remove the dot after the "table"). You might not be psychic, but your reply to my question was excellent and gave me lots of insight, so thank you again.

Comment: @user3383621 Do you expect to get back `"a cat jumped on the"` or `"a cat jumped on the table"`?

Comment: @Quincunx I guess since this would be the end of the sentence, it should be `"a cat jumped on the table" `

Comment: @user3383621 Then the easiest way is to append another `.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");`.

Comment: @Quincunx yes, that's what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = s[i].join(" ").replaceAll("\\b\\w*\\W+\\w*(?=\\b)", "").split(" ");
```

It joins the array with spaces, then applies the regex. The regex looks for a word break (`\b`), then a word with at least one non-word character (`\w*\W+\w*`), and then a word break at the end (not matched, there will still be a space). The `split` splits the string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String str[] ={ "123abass;[;[]","abcde","1234"};
    for(String s : str)
    {
        if(s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")) // should start and end with [a-zA-Z]
        System.out.println(s);
    }

O/P : abcde
```

Comment: in my case, if there is a word like " 123abass;[;[]_" in the array, it should be excluded completely, not trimmed off of the "bad" characters.

Comment: The `^` and `$` are not needed, as Java automatically acts as if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .toLowerCase() on each value in the array, then search the array against a-z values and it will be faster than a regular expression. Assume that your values are in an array called "myArray."

```
List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : myArray) {
  if(containsOnlyLetters(s)) {
    newValues.add(s);
  }
}
//do this if you have to go back to an array instead of an ArrayList
String[] newArray = (String[])newValues.toArray();
```

This is the containsOnlyLetters method:

```
boolean containsOnlyLetters(String input) {
  char[] inputLetters = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
  for(char c : inputLetters) {
    if(c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```